Best way to do a door arch for game asset
So when doing this arch i got this edges:

I solved like this:

An realized that i just need 2 support edges.

What is the best way to do this for a game asset? Someone told me the first one is better but with better triangle... I dont understand how...

Honestly, as a game asset it doesn't matter at all. The last version with two support edges is totally fine.

A game asset will be triangulated, so dissolving edges to make n-gons gains you nothing.

You have to consider two things:
1-It is a flat surface which does not need to deform so it does not matter if you leave than Geometry. It won’t affect you at all for textures.
2-If you plan to animate it, break it down, fracture it or similar, then better to have proper geometry with quads.
Keep in mind that modern game engines like Unreal engine don’t get their performance down due to geometry as the engine adapt it automatically depending on proximity to camera.
Good luck!

I understand the considerations. But I don't understand how it answers my question.
